# PL SQL table parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I would like pass a table type to a procedure as parameter.

```
create or replace package FOO is
    type FOOTYPE is record (
        FOOTYPE_A varchar2(5) null,
        FOOTYPE_B varchar2(5) null,
        FOOTYPE_C varchar2(5) null
    ); 

    type FOOTYPETABLE is table of FOOTYPE;
...
    procedure sendNew (
        table_a in FOOTYPETABLE
    ) is
        a number;
    begin
       ...
    end sendNew;
...
end FOO;

declare
    type bartabletype is table of FOO.FOOTYPE index by binary_integer;
    bartable bartabletype;
    begin
        bartable(0).FOOTYPE_A := '';
        bartable(0).FOOTYPE_B := '';
        bartable(0).FOOTYPE_C := '';
        bartable(1).FOOTYPE_A := '';
        bartable(1).FOOTYPE_B := '';
        bartable(1).FOOTYPE_C := '';
    FOO.sendNew(bartable);
end;
```

But Oracle says:

> "ora-00306 wrong number or types of arguments".

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to pass in an associative array (index by) when its expecting a pl/sql table (nested table).  For example, do this:

```
create or replace package tpkg as
  type t_myrec is record (
      val1 varchar2(1000),
      val2 varchar2(1000)
  );
  type t_myrec_tab is table of t_myrec;

  procedure recv_ary(i_ary in t_myrec_tab);
end;

create or replace package body tpkg as
    procedure recv_ary(i_ary in t_myrec_tab) is
    begin
      -- do something here
      dbms_output.put_line('Array has ' || i_ary.count || ' elements');
    end;
end;
```

And use it:

```
declare
  some_ary tpkg.t_myrec_tab;
begin
  select object_name, object_type
  bulk collect into some_ary
  from user_objects
  where rownum <= 100;

  tpkg.recv_ary(some_ary);
end;
```

Notice I declared "some_ary" as type "tpkg.t_myrec_tab".  In other words, I referenced the package type specifically, so I know its the correct type of collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `FOOTYPETABLE`, which is declared as the procedure sendNew() parameter type, is not the same as `table of FOO.FOOTYPETABLE`, which you are attempting to pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

`bartable`  variable must be of type `FOO.FOOTYPETABLE` and not `bartabletype`